# How do I allow GitHub secrets only in main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a public GitHub repository which runs a GitHub Actions workflow that builds the project and uploads it to a Maven repository server. In order to do this I need to store a username and password in GitHub secrets.

Is there anything stopping someone from creating a pull request to alter the workflow to try retrieve the secrets? Can I limit the secrets to only work on the main branch?

I'm aware that secrets are hidden from the logs, but there are still other ways they could retrieve them if they wanted.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment

Answer (score 0):

Secrets are protected by default on public repositories. But you can overcome this by mistake. But first. Please take a look here [Approving workflow runs from public forks](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks)

> Anyone can fork a public repository, and then submit a pull request that proposes changes to the repository's GitHub Actions workflows. Although workflows from forks do not have access to sensitive data such as secrets, they can be an annoyance for maintainers if they are modified for abusive purposes.
>
> To help prevent this, workflows on pull requests to public repositories from some outside contributors will not run automatically, and might need to be approved first. By default, all first-time contributors require approval to run workflows.

But pay attention to `pull_request_target` trigger

> Note: Workflows triggered by pull_request_target events are run in the context of the base branch. Since the base branch is considered trusted, workflows triggered by these events will always run, regardless of approval settings. For more information about the pull_request_target event, see "Events that trigger workflows."

Comment: Thats useful information, thanks. However there are some people in the github team who can create new branches without forks. Is there a way i can prevent them from retriving a secret, or is that just a risk i need to accept?

Comment: You should use your secrets mainly for accessing your private resources. Thus they are more common for CD part and not build. If you use environments with pepper gate approval you will protects your secrets, Rl especially that you could limit your deployments to specific branch.